# is there a way to enable optimization for local clang++ on mac?

Tags: c++, clang

this question is derived from that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56552706/10443608).

it seems that the online [compiler](http://cpp.sh/7yzcp) discard this function while optimizing.

```
void functiona()
{
    long long number = 0;
    // long long problemSize = 100000000000;
    long long problemSize = 10;

    for( long long i = 0; i < problemSize; ++i )
    {
       for(long long j = 0; j < problemSize; j++)
       {
           for(long long k = 0; k < problemSize; k++)
           {
               for(long long l = 0; l < problemSize; l++)
               {
                   for(long long l = 0; l < problemSize; l++)
                   {
                       number++;
                       number--;
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

compiling [this piece of code](http://cpp.sh/7yzcp) on my local mac

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ benchmark.cpp

./a.out
409
```

seems to be without optimization.

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels) and [doc](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#optimization-level) provide some info about clang optimization.

is there a way to enable optimization for clang++, so that the local output is close to online one.

Comment: Do you mean [`-O3`](https://godbolt.org/z/VDKA37)?

Comment: Frankly I'm amazed that compiles on your mac. using the posted source and verbatim build command on my mac with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) causes an ambiguity error on `function`. [Friends don't let friends use  `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Did you encounter some problem when reading the manual for your compiler?

Answer (score 1):

`clang++` takes basically the same switches as `clang`, which are fully covered in the links you found on your own. The obvious one for maximum optimization would be `-Ofast`, but given how simple and obvious this optimization is, basically any level of optimization is likely to trigger it, `-O3`, `-02`, `-Os`, even `-O1`. The exact behavior will vary by compiler version, so you can experiment to determine the minimal level needed to eliminate the loop on your version.